# How detect the students that have exams in consecutive days?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table of (Examdata) that contains 7 columns:

(Class_ID, Subject_ID, Student_ID, Subject_name, exam_days, exam_dates, exam_times)

I want to detect "student_id" that has exam and another exam in next day, for example:

```
| student_id | subject_name | exam_days | exam_date |
|------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|
| 1          |  math        | Sunday    | 2/4/2019  |
| 1          | physical     | Monday    | 3/4/2019  |
```

Here the student_id="1" have two exam in Consecutive days, maybe the student_id more than that for that I want to detect them.

Note: if the student has an exam on Thursday m and on Sunday should not be considered because the weekend between them.

### This is my try:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Exams");

$array1 = array();

$n = "SELECT DISTINCT exam_dates FROM Examdata ORDER BY exam_dates";

$queryarray1 = mysqli_query($con, $n) or die("Error in query: $queryarray1. ".mysqli_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryarray1)) {
    $array1[] = $row;
}

// print_r($array1);

/* the output for this :

Array ( [0] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-02 ) [1] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-03 ) [2] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-04 ) [3] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-05 ) [4] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-06 ) [5] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-08 ) [6] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-09 ) [7] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-10 ) [8] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-11 ) [9] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-12 ) [10] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-13 ) [11] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-15 ) [12] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-16 ) [13] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-17 ) [14] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-18 ) [15] => Array ( [exam_dates] => 1440-04-20 ) )
*/

$b = json_encode($array1);

$z = sizeof($array1);

for ($i = 0; $i < $z; $i++) {
    $search = "SELECT *  
            FROM Examdata e1
            ( 
               SELECT * 
               FROM examdata e2 where e1.exam_dates == $b[$i] && e2.exam_dates==$b($i++)  && e1.Student_ID==e2.Student_ID && e1.exam_days!='Thursday' && e2.exam_days!='sunday'
               ORDER BY `exam_dates`,`Student_ID `
            )";

    $querysearch = mysqli_query($con, $search) or die("Error in query: $querysearch. ".mysqli_error($con));

    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($querysearch)) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $result['Class_ID'] .
         '</td><td>' . $result['Subject_ID'] .
         '</td><td>' . $result['Student_ID'] .
         '</td><td>' . $result['Subject_name'].
         '</td><td>' . $result['exam_days'] .
         '</td><td>' . $result['exam_dates'] .
         '</td><td>' . $result['exam_times'] .
         '</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Message error:

> Error in query: . You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(SELECT * from examdata e2 where e1.exam_dates==[
>   && e2.exam_dates=' at line 2

-- 
but I don't know how to pass array in query.

Comment: Without table structure and example data this question is not clear... You would most likely have the use windows function like LAG() / LEAD() in combation with DATEDIFF() or use a co-related subquery in combination with DATEDIFF()

Comment: Hey, you're probably new to stackoverflow, i advise you to share your Table schema, it will make it easier for us to give you a solution :D

Comment: @dharman you're confusing project development with project deployment

Comment: @Strawberry What is your comment in relation to? I do not understand you.

Comment: `mysqli_error()` is an error because it is missing an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a solution that works, and try to think on a better / more optimized one.

so what we need to do is to join the Table with itself on the student_id, then we need to check if the exam1 comes 1 day after the exam2 using the DATEDIFF function.

this is the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT examData1.student_id, examData1.subject_name as first_subject_name, examData2.subject_name as next_subject_name , examData1.exam_days as first_exam_day, examData2.exam_days as next_exam_day, examData1.exam_date, examData2.exam_date
FROM Examdata as examData1, Examdata as examData2
WHERE examData1.student_id = examData2.student_id AND DATEDIFF(examData2.exam_date,examData1.exam_date) = 1
```

check this [link](https://paiza.io/projects/IqSWp-9UR7mROjgxSu30bw?language=mysql) to test the query.

note: you should check SQL syntax cause the error you're getting a syntax error.

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you ..<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3

Answer (score 0):

Get the exam dates order by date, then you can use something like this in PHP, or your solution needs to be "pure SQL"?

```
$currentStudent = 0;
$lastCheckedDate = 0;
$listOfStudentsWithConsecutiveDates = [];

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )  ) {
    if( $currentStudent == $row['student_id'] ) {
       if( isset($listOfStudentsWithConsecutiveDates[ $row['student_id'] ]) ) continue;
       $datediff = strtotime( $row['exam_date'] ) - $lastCheckedDate;
       if( round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24)) == 1 ) {
           $listOfStudentsWithConsecutiveDates[ $row['student_id'] ] = $row;
       );
    } else {
       $currentStudent = $row['student_id'];
       $lastCheckedDate = strtotime( $row['exam_date'] );
    }
}
```

You will get an array with

```
$listOfStudentsWithConsecutiveDates[ student_id ] = first exam which is consecutive to another one for this student
```